# Validates acceptance always failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I can't see what I'm missing, but something is obviously not right.

In model:

```
validates :terms, :acceptance => true, :on => :update
```

Trying a few options:

```
>> a = Factory(:blog_agreement)
=> #<BlogAgreement id: 54, terms: false, created_at: "2011-01-20 11:33:03", updated_at: "2011-01-20 11:33:03", accept_code: "fa27698206bb15a6fba41857f12841c363c0e291", user_id: 874>

>> a.terms
=> false

>> a.terms = true
=> true
>> a.save
=> false

>> a.terms = "1"
=> "1"
>> a.save
=> false

>> a.terms = 1
=> 1
>> a.save
=> false
>> a.errors.full_messages
=> ["Terms must be accepted"]
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

#### Updated answer..

So it turns out that the problem was having terms as an actual column in the table. In general validates_acceptance_of is used without such a column, in which case it defines an attribute accessor and uses that for its validation.

In order for validates_acceptance_of to work when it maps to a real table column it is necessary to pass the :accept option, like:

```
validates :terms, :acceptance => {:accept => true}
```

The reason for this has to do with typecasting in Active Record. When the named attribute actually exists, AR performs typecasting based on the database column type. In most cases the acceptance column will be defined as a boolean and so `model_object.terms` will return true or false.

When there's no such column `attr_accessor :terms` simply returns the value passed in to the model object from the params hash which will normally be `"1"` from a checkbox field.

Comment: Thanks. Doh! Yes, I didn't realize it was *only* for virtual fields. But yes, Factory(:whatever) creates the object, then I was updating it in above examples.

Comment: Cool. You could keep your db column for terms and use a different validator but really, if one assumes that user records can only be created when the terms are accepted then there's not really any need for it.

Comment: Ah, my reasoning was the object gets created by an admin, then the end user accepts the agreement (hence validation of terms just on update). I also do want to store whether they've been accepted or not. It's cool, I can fix it up from here, just would have been very short and simple if that worked

Comment: Just reading through the code for the AcceptanceValidator, it seems you can use it when the attribute maps to a database column. For that to work you must pass `:accept => true` when declaring the validation. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/acceptance.rb

Comment: .. my previous comment assumes that your terms field is a boolean. If not, :accept should be whatever your truth value is in that context, bearing in mind that AR will type-cast the value so it won't always be the same as the value from params[].

Comment: For people like me, conversely, change `:acceptance => {:accept => true}` to `:acceptance => true` if you don't have a column in the database.

Answer (score 8):

In the case of someone has the same problem like me with devise, i add this answer:

i added to the devise's registration form:

**sign_up.html.erb**

```
<%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
```

**user.rb**

```
validates, :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
```

i forgot to add :terms_of_service inside my configured_permitted_parameters and devise ignored the checkbox state.

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :terms_of_service)}
end
```

The **configure_permitted_parameters** method is used by devise for know what params he should be save in addition of email and password.

Comment: i have tried your answer but did not get the desired result

Comment: I need to know more about your problem. You can create a new question with your code and post here the url. I will be happy to help you ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had to use this format:

```
validates :accpeted_terms, :acceptance => {:accept => true}
```

Comment: But most probably without the typo in your validated attribute, as it currently reads as `accpeted_terms`.

Comment: I had trouble with this in postgres. The Rails Guide says acceptance: true defaults to values ['1', true]. But adding ( accept: true } effectively removes '1' as an accepted value and it always fails

Answer (score 4):

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms, :accept => true
```

Comment: The other answers don't work with Rails 3. This answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I found Candland's answer above for validates acceptance to be correct in Rails 3.1. This is how I set up my Rails 3.1.3 app to record the acceptance to the database.

In the migration,

```
class AddTermsToAccount < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :accounts, :terms_of_service, :boolean, :default => false
  end
end
```

In the model,

```
attr_accessible :terms_of_service
validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => {:accept => true}
```

In the form,

```
<%= f.check_box :terms_of_service %>
<%= f.label :terms_of_service %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this from Angular JS and Rails 4. Angular send parameter with `true` value but rails did not recognize `true`.

> It can receive an :accept option, which determines the value that will
>   be considered acceptance. It defaults to "1" and can be easily
>   changed.

So, I change into this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { accept: true }
end
```

If you have default parameter is `1` or `0`. Try to do this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
end
```

This is for more documentation. [acceptance validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance).
I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

A call to a factory creates the record, so your subsequent calls to save are in fact updates, so your validation fails as intended. Try it without the factory and it should work.

Comment: But she is accepting the terms and the validation still fails.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a basic checkbox in your view, such as

```
<%= builder.check_box :agreement %>
```

just put this line in your model

```
validates :agreement, :acceptance => true
```

which uses the default "1" generated by the check_box view helper