# How to properly add acceptance validator to form in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, validation

I would like to add simple terms validator to my form:

**Model**

```
attr_accessor :terms
validates :terms, :acceptance => {:accept => true}, :allow_nil => false
```

**View**(simple_form)

```
= simple_form_for @student, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
   ...
= f.input :terms, as: :select
= f.button :submit
```

But I get:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: terms
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746710/validates-acceptance-always-failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
field :terms, :type => Boolean, :default => false
attr_accessible :terms
validates :terms, :acceptance => {:accept => true}
```

On your view:

```
<%= f.input :agree, :as => :boolean, label: false %>
```

Regards!

Comment: Hi, I get error when send checked terms => ``... "terms"=>"0"}``

Comment: You must add a field boolean to your model. I have edited my response. For example with mongoid you can add to your model `field :terms, :type => Boolean, :default => false`, If you use activerecord you have make a migration!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a column or `attr_accessor` for it, otherwise it will be a class object.

What you can do is

```
attr_accessible :terms
validates_acceptance_of :terms

<%= f.check_box :terms%> I agree to ....
```