# validates :terms, acceptance: true not showing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

In my model I have the following validator:

```
validates :terms, acceptance: true, on: :create, allow_nil: false
attr_accessor :terms
```

and in my form I have:

```
= simple_form_for @reservation do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :terms, as: :boolean
```

The problem is that when user not accept the terms it not showing any error, why?

Comment: try with acceptance: false

Comment: When I add acceptance: false it not require from user to accept the terms.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746710/validates-acceptance-always-failing

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
validates :terms, :acceptance => {:accept => true} , on: :create, allow_nil: false
```

Comment: `allow_nil: false` saved me. Thanks!

Comment: As Eric G pointed out below you will still need to add :acceptance to your permitted parameters. allow_nil: false is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

Problem may have terms as an actual column in the table. In general validates_acceptance_of is used without such a column, in which case it defines an attribute accessor and uses that for its validation.

In order for validates_acceptance_of to work when it maps to a real table column it is necessary to pass the :accept option, like:

```
validates :terms, :acceptance => {:accept => true} , :on => :create , allow_nil: false
```

The reason for this has to do with typecasting in Active Record. When the named attribute actually exists, AR performs typecasting based on the database column type. In most cases the acceptance column will be defined as a boolean and so `model_object.terms` will return true or false.

When there's no such column `attr_accessor :terms` simply returns the value passed in to the model object from the params hash which will normally be `"1"` from a checkbox.

Via noodl

Comment: Thank's for help but this is not solving the problem. It still not showing any validation errors.

Answer (score 4):

I may have had a similar problem (Rails 4.2.0). I created a checkbox, but it would be ignored and never report and error if unchecked. I found that adding the parameter to the `.permit` part of my [Strong Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) allowed it to be present.

In my view template for my `_form` I have something like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :tos, 'I accepts the TOS' %><br>
  <%= f.check_box :tos %>
</div>
```

I generated my model using scaffold, so my `create` method start like this

```
def create
  @thing = Thing.new(thing_params)
```

then near the bottom I have the following for `thing_params`

```
def thing_params
  params.require(:thing).permit(:field1, :field2, :tos)
end
```

in my model I used the following:

```
validates_acceptance_of :tos
```

If I leave out ':tos`like this`params.require(:thing).permit(:field1, :field2) it will not pop up an error and allows it to continue. This seems counter-intuitive because if Strong Parameters is removing the :tos field then I would think the validate_acceptance would fail.

I had initially just create a checkbox without using `f.check_box`. Now, if I even try to call the `new` route without `:tos`" being listed as permitted, rails throws an error. There also seems to be some rails magic going on because if I remove the `validates_acceptance_of` from my model, I receive an `NoMethodError` error when rendering my view saying `undefined method`tos'` for the line

```
<%= f.check_box :tos %>
```

Would be great if someone else could explain what exactly is going on as I just hacked this together from googling and guessing.

Comment: True: you need to add your acceptance param to the strong parameters. If you don't do that and submit the form, the form will be accepted regardless of the state of checkbox.