# validates_acceptance_of working but not saving true user:age_valid in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

The validate_acceptance_of is working but it is not saving the true to the db user column age_valid if checked.

users.controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
.
.
.
private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :birthdate, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation, :age_valid)
end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
.
.
.
<%= f.input :age_valid, 
            :as => :boolean, 
            :label => false, 
            :inline_label => 'I am 18 years of age or older.' %>
.
.
.
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :remember_token, :age_valid
.
.
.
validates_acceptance_of :age_valid, 
        :acceptance => true,
        :message => "You must verify that you are at least 18 years of age."
```

This all works accept it does not change the database column "age_valid" from false to true. I need this to happen for record keeping.

Here is the translated DOM

```
<div class="form-group boolean optional user_age_valid">
   <div class="checkbox">
   <input value="0" type="hidden" name="user[age_valid]">
   <label><input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[age_valid]" id="user_age_valid"> I am 18 years of age or older.</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Migration used

```
class AddAgeValidToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   add_column :users, :age_valid, :boolean, default: false
end
end
```

Comment: [I get the feeling that you should be using `:accept` instead of `:acceptance`.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_acceptance_of)

Comment: @Makoto If I change `:acceptance` to `:accept` it tosses back the error message.

Comment: What does the HTML look like for the form you're generating?  It could be the case that it's not populating the form style correctly.

Comment: Added the DOM to the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validates acceptance always failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4746710/validates-acceptance-always-failing)

Comment: Its not a duplicate question as I based this code from that question and its answers. My code is working except for the database column going from false to true. I could live with this the way it is and remove the column from the DB but I want it for record keeping that I can prove the user accepted the terms.

Comment: Do you actually have a `users.age_valid` database column? In that case you can remove `attr_accessor :age_valid`. If you have an accessor but not a DB column then your validation will pass but nothing will be saved to the database.

Comment: If I take the `attr_accessor :age_valid` out the validation fails and I get the error message. I do have the users table column age_valid. I'll add the migration file to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works for me.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_acceptance_of :age_valid,
:accept => true,
:message => "You must verify that you are at least 18 years of age."

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.input :age_valid, 
        :as => :boolean, 
        :label => false, 
        :checked_value => true,
        :unchecked_value => false,
        :inline_label => 'I am 18 years of age or older.' %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

I removed attribute accessor and changed `:acceptance => true,` to `:accept => true` and added `:checked_value => true,:unchecked_value => false`

Comment: This worked perfectly for both create and update. The database is now showing the correct saved value. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You have accidentally mixed together two syntactic ways of defining validations.

New syntax:

```
validates :field,
  property: {setting: "value"}
```

Old syntax:

```
validates_property_of :field, setting: "value"
```

The short way -- remove `acceptance` option from parameters, as it's already stated in a method name.

If you'd rather prefer a new syntax, here's what it looks like:

```
validates :age_valid, acceptance: {message: "..."}
```

In this specific case there's no gain from using new syntax. However, in other cases it allows you to validate attributes with multiple criteria without repeating them or resorting to metaprogramming.

When it comes to code maintainability, stay consistent: choose either one or the other and use it wherever needed in your project.